# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string / No return

Tags: php

The problem is that $price return nothing.

I'm using https://github.com/PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator for the TOTP part of the code.

I have tried to play around with settype() for the $price, but seems like it doesn't really work.

If I change $obj->data->prices[0]->price to $obj->data. I get this error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in

```
<?php

$secret ="(Verify Secret)";
$api = "(API Key)";

require_once 'GoogleAuthenticator.php';

$ga = new PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator();

$oneCode = $ga->getCode($secret);

$itemName=str_replace(array(' ','"','\'','\\\'','\\'),array('%20',null,null,null,null),$_GET['name']);

$url = "https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=" . $api . "&code=" . $oneCode . "&names=" . $itemName . "&delimiter=!END!";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$obj = curl_exec($curl);
$obj = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);

$price = $obj->data->prices[0]->price;

echo "Price: ".$price."<br>";
echo "itemName: ".$itemName."<br>";
echo "url: ".$url;

?>
```

Comment: The message says it. Your `$price` is an object, but you're using it as a string. Try `$price = json_encode($obj->data->prices[0]->price);` to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is kind of embarrassing as the problem is that I disabled API access shortly and forgot to turn it on again.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of debugging have you done? Have you done a `var_dump()` for each var you've declared to see what gets returned?

I looked at the [bitskins api](https://bitskins.com/api), and I don't see "get_item_price" as an option.

Are you sure that you don't mean to use [get_price_data_for_items_on_sale](https://bitskins.com/api#get_price_data_for_items_on_sale)?

Comment: get_item_price is not listed on the page, but it's working as it should.